# Can I change the use of two ? : shortcuts to use the new switch expression syntax?

Tags: c#

I have code that looks like this. I wonder if I could replace this with a switch expression type of code:

```
var ptsMsg1 = !App.cards ?
             "" :
             selectedPoints == pointsCount ?
                " This is the same number as when you started your practice." :
               $" This is {(selectedPoints - pointsCount)} more.";
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be more legible as an if / else if / else block?

Comment: Will there be more extending results in the future? If not, John 's suggestion is better. `? :` could be translate to `if else` easily. Nested `? :` is a disaster. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# 8 switch expression can be used for that:

```
var msg2 = (App.cards, samePoints: selectedPoints == pointsCount) switch
        {
            { cards: false } => "",
            { samePoints: true } => " This is the same number as when you started your practice.",
            _ => $" This is {(selectedPoints - pointsCount)} more.",
        };
```

My answer is just a response to the question. Whether this or OP's code is more maintainable is subjective anyway.

Comment: Can you explain what this means:   (App.cards, samePoints: selectedPoints == pointsCount). Sorry but I've never seen anything like this before.

Comment: It is named tuple. It can be used to group some values together as an object. If you try to declare `var a = (App.cards, samePoints: selectedPoints == pointsCount)` and use IntelliSense, you'll see there are `cards` and `samePoints` property.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this

```
switch (App.cards) 
{
  case true:
    switch (selectedPoints == pointsCount)
    {
      case true:
        return " This is the same number as when you started your practice.";

      default:
        return "";
   }

  default:
    return $" This is {(selectedPoints - pointsCount)} more.";
}
```

**I do not recommend you use this, I have just answered your question.**

Comment: Correct, but ugly :/

Comment: @MarkusDeibel I agree with you.